# Is there a way to get only User item from a collection using Mongoose DB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

So this is my Schema folder:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model(
    'premium', 
    new mongoose.Schema({
        User: String,
        Name: String,
        Expire: Number,
        Permanent: Boolean,
    })
);
```

So I want to get from database only User and Name items and use it in embed on discord.js, but I am not finding any way to do so

Comment: It's shown in pretty much [the first example in the querying documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` and specify field you want with 1 and not with 0 :

```
dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}).select({ "User": 1, "Name": 1});
```